# Sending multiple JSON request to server under one request nodejs

Tags: json, node.js, request, google-drive-realtime-api

I have some files downloaded and I wanna push them to a server. Every time I try to push the file I get the error
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.

I have a for loop that reads all the files and parse them and after that I want to send them to the server one by one.

```
app.get('/dataparser', function(req, res) {
var fs = require('fs');
var obj;
var jsonGis = new Array();
var jsonArray;
var filePaths = [];
const downloadFolder = './sampletest/';
var mtimes = {};
var reloadTimes = 10000;
fs.readdir(downloadFolder, (err, files) => {
    files.forEach(file => {
      filePaths.push("sampletest/" + file);
    });
})
var execFunction = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < filePaths.length; i++) {
        parseFile(filePaths[i], mtimes[filePaths[i]]);
    }
};
execFunction();
setInterval(execFunction, reloadTimes);
function parseFile(fileName, lastModifiedTime) {
    fs.stat(fileName, function(err, fd) {
            for (var i=0, len = filePaths.length; i<len; i++) {
              if (fd.mtime !== lastModifiedTime) {
                  mtimes[fileName] = fd.mtime;
                  fs.readFile(filePaths[i], function(err, data) {
                    if (err) {
                        return console.error(err);
                    }
                    obj = JSON.parse(data);
                    jsonGis.push('"Person1"');
                    jsonGis.push('"' + obj.pages[1].answers[2].values[0] + '"');
                    jsonGis.push('"person2"');
                    jsonGis.push('"' + obj.pages[1].answers[0].values[0] + '"');
                    jsonGis.push('"codewals"');
                    jsonGis.push('"42343GSDS"');
                    jsonGis.push('"geometry":{');
                    jsonGis.push('"x":' + obj.pages[1].answers[4].values[0].coordinates.latitude + ',');
                    jsonGis.push('"y":' + obj.pages[1].answers[4].values[0].coordinates.longitude);
                    var str = "[{ " + jsonGis[0] + jsonGis[1] + jsonGis[2] + ": " + jsonGis[3] + "," + jsonGis[4] + ": " + jsonGis[16] + "}}]"
                    //pushing to the server
                    console.log("check here");
                    console.log(str);
                    var qs = require("querystring");
                    var http = require("http");
                    var options = {
                        "method": "POST",
                        "hostname": "twst2.gtw.com",
                        "port": null,
                        "path": "localpath/",
                        "headers": {
                            "accept": "application/json",
                            "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                        }
                    };
                    var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
                        var chunks = [];

                        res.on("data", function(chunk) {
                            chunks.push(chunk);
                        });

                        res.on("end", function() {
                            var body = Buffer.concat(chunks);
                            console.log(body.toString());
                        });
                    });
                    req.write(qs.stringify({features: str}));
                    res.send("The server was updated");
                    req.end();
                  });
            }
        }
    });
};
```

Just need to send the data to the server from file1.json and then file2.json then file3.json and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try creating a separate callback function that includes .write, .send, and .end, then let it be the callback for .request.

Comment: Kinda new the node not sure how to do that

Comment: @Slygoth - [this site](http://callbackhell.com/) does a fine job of explaining callbacks in general and has some working examples. It's the best write-up I've found so far. There are also some good node-specific resources [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/nodejs_callbacks_concept.htm)

Comment: Thanks much Michael checking it out now